# single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: oracle

I am getting the following error : "single-row subquery returns more than one row"while trying to execute the following query :

```
select * 
from wm_inventory 
where item_id =(select item_cbo.item.id  
                from item_cbo 
                where item_name in ('564310','140270'));
```

Comment: Use IN clause instead of equality check `item_id =`

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off joining the two tables and then filtering?

Comment: @Fred - no, the OP would **not** be better off joining the two tables; the `IN` solution, suggested by Jaydip, is more efficient. An `IN` condition does only as much work as needed to determine if an id is or is not in a list; an actual join does more work than that.

Comment: What's with the two dots in `item_cbo.item.id`, which none of the Answers seem to catch? Did you mean `item_cbo.item_id`?

Answer (score 2):

Change to this:

```
select * 
from wm_inventory 
where item_id   in  (select item_cbo.item.id  
                from item_cbo 
                where item_name in ('564310','140270'));
```

You can't return multiple rows for an "=" operator.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty obvious.  Use `in`:

```
select i.* 
from wm_inventory i 
where i.item_id in (select item_cbo.item.id  
                    from item_cbo 
                    where item_name in ('564310', '140270')
                   );
```